# How to provide installation spesific configuration for React app at runtime?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, configuration

In Python applications I can do the following, changing `settings.py` contents per application deployment:

```
# settings.py
SOME_VARIABLE = 123
SOME_URL = "https://example.com/"

# myapp.py
from . import settings

do_something(settings.SOME_VARIABLE)
fetch_data(settings.SOME_URL)
```

How I can achieve the same thing with React app?

Note that in my case same react app is deployed hundreds of times to different servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your React starter check the docs on how to pass an environment variable.

See [Adding Custom Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) with Create-React-App.

```
# .env
REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE=abcdef
```

Or just treat it like a normal object:

```
// settings.js
const settings = {
  url: "https://example.com/",
};

export default settings;

// usage
import settings from "./settings.js";
do_something(settings.url);
```

Comment: As I understood environment variables are done at build time and not when react app is loaded? I do realize that it's JS and has nothing like reading files at runtime but how I can for example tell which is the right base url to access my API without recompilation?

Comment: If you don't want to add it in build time just treat it like a normal object, I'll add an example

Comment: So if i put settings.js next to main.js (or whatever my compiled file is) above will work?